# Purpose of keyword latest instead of version number with caret sign

Tags: node.js, npm

Could someone explain to me the difference on using the keyword `latest` over the vaerion-caret pattern `^1.0.0`.

For e.g when I want to install material ui inside an existing project I tried this at first:

**Project A**

```
"dependencies": {
   "next": "latest",
    "react": "latest",
    "react-dom": "latest"
  }
```

**Project B**

```
"dependencies": {
    "next": "12.1.2",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0"
  }
```

I run this command on both Projects
`npm i @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled`

Project B resolved into this:

```
Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.0" from @mui/material@5.5.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!   @mui/material@"*" from the root project
```

Where as Project A, which uses the latest keyword works fine.
But it does not install React 18.x.x though.

It confuses me because I thought that the `latest` keyword always resolved the latest package registered / taged inside npm.

I first stumbeld on this usage at the material ui repo and this then got me confused:
https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/examples/nextjs/package.json

Answer (score 0):

The first option is meant to grab the current stable release of package. On the other hand for caret ranges, only major version must match. Any minor or patch version greater than or equal to the minimum is valid.

The caret version, ^18.0.0 permits versions from 18.0.0 all the way up to, but not including, the next major version, 19.0.0.

Comment: I updated my initial question a little further baucause I understand the main reason on using caret but I'm still confused on the behavior when using the `latest` keyword.